# How to create API references for AS3 class packages?

Tags: actionscript-3

I have build a simple framework using AS3. I need to generate API reference for class packages used to build this framework.

Can I utilize the comments specified inside these classes to auto generate API reference.

Thanks,

Rajneesh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Natural Docs](http://www.naturaldocs.org/) or Grant Skinner's wrapper for AsDoc [AsDocr](http://gskinner.com/blog/archives/2010/01/asdocr_simple_a.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the asdoc tool, its included in the SDK.
https://www.google.nl/search?q=asdoc+tool

Comment: AsDocr is a wrapper for AsDoc tool from SDK:)